# How to synchronise slideDown and addClass so the animation works properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout

I'd like to slide down my ul when clicked, that is normally hidden by css. In case if I add the class ".open" before the slideDown, then the '500' duration doesn't work, but if I setTimeOut for addClass("open") for '500', then it doesn't slide down until the setTimeOut expires. 
How could I synchronise these two, so it doesn't delay the opening and it's not even opens it without a duration of 500?

```js
if(!jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("open")){
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open").children("ul").slideDown(500);
}
```

```css
li:not(.open)>ul {
    display: none;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

This is the version where it appears without animation.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Snippets is to let you show **runnable** examples of your problem. The above isn't runnable; making it runnable by adding the other necessary bits will help you get answers.

Comment: All the jQuery effect methods have completion callbacks. See docs

Comment: `jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open").children("ul").hide().slideDown(500);` this works much better now, however it's not the prettiest solution to first display it with css then right away hide it to get it slide down then.

Answer (score 0):

The following code below has resolved my issue:

```js
jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open").children("ul").hide()‌​.slideDown(500);
```